# About Cache-Control

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

is there any way to set all files from a bucket to have a default cache-control as public and public,max-age=7776000? If not, how should I adapt my PHP code to work with multipart upload?

Here is my media upload code:

```
$file_up            = file_get_contents($file['full_path']);

clearstatcache();                        

$file['size']       = filesize($file['full_path']);
$access_token       = $this->googleapi->get_access_token();                             

$header = array(
    'Content-Type: audio/mp3',
    'Content-Length: '.$file['size'].''
);

$url    = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/MY_BUCKET/o?uploadType=media&predefinedAcl=publicRead&name=".$file['name_ext'].'&access_token='.$access_token;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_up);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
$dxa = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Maybe it would be easier for you to use the official google cloud storage SDK ? https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.24.0/storage/storageclient

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the "cacheControl" property as part of the upload. To do this, you'd do a `multipart` or a `resumable` uploadType, and you'd set the cacheControl as part of the metadata that you assign. Follow the guides here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

That said, this would be substantially easier to do via the [PHP SDK](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/):

```
$options = [
    'name' => '/images/new-name.jpg',
    'metadata' => [
       'cacheControl' => 'public,max-age=7776000'
]];
$object = $bucket->upload(
    fopen(__DIR__ . '/image.jpg', 'r'),
    $options);
```